# Error creating WebSocket connection using AsyncHttpClient behind Squid Proxy

Tags: proxy, websocket, squid, asynchttpclient, java-websocket

Library in use: 
AsyncHtpClient Library: 
Version : 1.9.32
Location: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

Netty Version : 3.10.3.Final

Proxy: Squid Proxy

I am trying to create a websocket connection using AsyncHttpClinet library. It works fine when using without the proxy.
But when I start a proxy and pass in the Host, port, username and password , I am unable to create a websocket connection.

It get a stack trace which says Invalid Status Code 400:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid Status Code 400
    at com.ning.http.client.ws.WebSocketUpgradeHandler.onCompleted(WebSocketUpgradeHandler.java:76)
    at com.ning.http.client.ws.WebSocketUpgradeHandler.onCompleted(WebSocketUpgradeHandler.java:29)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.future.NettyResponseFuture.getContent(NettyResponseFuture.java:177)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.future.NettyResponseFuture.done(NettyResponseFuture.java:214)
    ... 35 more
```

I am setting the proxy object like this:

```
ProxyServer ps = new ProxyServer("host-name",portNo,"user_name","password");

AsyncHttpClientConfig cf = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setProxyServer(ps).build();
WebSocket websocket = c.prepareGet(url) 
                .execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder().addWebSocketListener( 
                        new WebSocketTextListener() { 
                            @Override 
                            public void onMessage(String message) { 

                            } 

                            @Override 
                            public void onFragment(String s, boolean b) { 
                            } 

                            @Override 
                            public void onOpen(WebSocket websocket) { 
                            } 

                            @Override 
                            public void onClose(WebSocket websocket) { 
                            } 

                            @Override 
                            public void onError(Throwable t) { 
                            } 
                        } 

                ).build() 
                ).get();
```

Are there any other steps to configure a proxy for websocket connections?

I have also tried configuring the ProxyServer object like this:

```
ProxyServer ps = new ProxyServer(ProxyServer.Protocol.HTTPS,"host-name",portNo,"user_name","password");
```

Comment: Which version do you use? Did you try with latest 2.0.0-RC7?

Comment: @StephaneLandelle No, I tried with 1.9.32. (Updated the question to reflect that)
I can try with the 2.0.0-RC7 and report back. In the meantime any guesses why this could be?

Comment: A guess? Yeah, a bug...

Comment: @StephaneLandelle, I am new to Maven, but Using this in the POM file deons't recognize the latest version:

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-client-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-RC7</version>
        </dependency>

I guess it's not up on Maven yet. I will try with adding as a Jar.

Comment: Wrong groupId and artifactId: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.asynchttpclient%7Casync-http-client%7C2.0.0-RC7%7Cjar

Comment: @StephaneLandelle, thanks for your help with this. I have the dependency imported, but it does look like the class hierarchy has changed. My previous code isn't compatible with the new changes. I will read up and update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101684/discussion-between-sudhanshu-and-stephane-landelle).